# Orthogonality, proof in Linear Algebra/Functional Analysi

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

> Problem: Let $M$ be a complete subspace Y and $x \in X$ fixed. Then $z = x - y \perp Y$
>
> **Part of the Proof**
>
> If $z \perp Y$ were false, there would be a $y_1 \in Y$ such that $\langle z, y_1 \rangle = \beta \neq 0$. Clearly $y_1 \neq 0$ since otherwise $\langle z, y_1 \rangle = 0$. Furthermore for any scalar $\alpha$,
>
> $\| z  - \alpha y_1 \|^2 = \langle z - \alpha y_1, z - \alpha y_1 \rangle$

Could someone explain to me why the proof suddenly jumps to $\| z - \alpha y_1 \|^2$?? Why are we considering such a creature in the first place? I don't see the logic following here

**EDIT**. Oh no, what's wrong? Why $-2$?

Comment: I think people see a picture and automatically think it's a bad question.

Comment: I'll write out the proof.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary!! I wouldn't worry about the people who down voted.

Comment: Your question is not very well formulated. What is $y$?

Comment: $y$ is an element of $Y$

Comment: Well, now I can't see the other part of the proof to see why they would choose to look at $\| z - \alpha y_1 \|^2$, but my best guess is that it's for ease of notation to avoid square roots and to work directly with the inner product.

Comment: Now actually what I really want to know is why $\| z - -ay_1\|$ at all?

Comment: Is this from Kreyszig? I'll go look at it.

Comment: Yes it is. page 160

Comment: @sizz, your question begins "Let M be a complete subspace Y and $\,x\in X\,$..." . This already is messy: did you mean M is a subspace of Y? And what is $\,X\,$ ?! You see, these are the things downvoters go for wildly, as annoying as I think downvoting a question is without, *at least*, giving the OP a chance to correct his post. Well, now you have a chance: **be careful** !

Comment: Actually this was how the problem was posed, but I assumed your interpretation was how I read the problem

Comment: Posting a nonsensical\sloppy question just because "that's the way it was writtent" is a rather poor explanation for a sloppy\nonsensical question.  If you don't understand what's going on how would you expect others to understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so they're making the assumption that $z = x - y$ right from the start and so $z - \alpha y_1 = x - y - \alpha y_1$. This means that $\|z - \alpha y_1\| = \|x - (y+\alpha y_1)\| \geq \inf\limits_{\tilde{y} \in M} \|x - \tilde{y}\| = \delta$ since the infimum over all $\tilde{y}$ must necessarily be smaller than the case with specific $y + \alpha y_1$. The goal of the proof is to find a contradiction to this fact by assuming that $z \perp Y$ does not hold. This is why they're working with $\| z - \alpha y_1\|$, trying to manipulate it in such a way to show that $\|z - \alpha y_1 \| < \delta$ giving a contradiction.

Comment: How does assuming $\langle z , y_1  \rangle \neq 0 $ imply $\| z - \alpha y_1 \| < \delta$? I mean this is true of course, btu I see no relatioship here. It's like saying if a dog has four legs, then 1 + 2 = 3.

Comment: Well, it implies it for a specific $\alpha$ as given in the proof. The main part of the proof shows that these two quantities, which seemed totally unrelated at first, in fact are related.

Comment: I am still having a hard time understanding the relationship of the inner product not being 0 and the norm of z and -$\alpha y_1$

Comment: Note that $\beta = \langle z,y_1\rangle \neq 0$. The proof shows that then $$\|z - \alpha y_1 \| = \|z\|^2 - \frac{|\beta|^2}{\langle y_1, y_1\rangle}.$$ Now if the inner product $\langle z,y_1\rangle$ were zero, then no contradiction could be obtained since necessarily $\overline{\alpha} = \overline{\beta}/\langle y_1,y_1\rangle = 0$ by definition of it, and so $$\|z  \| - \frac{|\beta|^2}{\langle y_1, y_1\rangle} = \|z \|^2 = \delta^2.$$ However, since $\beta \neq 0$, you're subtracting a positive quantity and so it must be strictly less than $\delta^2$.